# Subsetting in Logistic Regression modeling in R

Tags: r, regression

I received the following error messages when splitting and subsetting my data in the process of logistic regression in R. I am stuck at the "subset" step.

```
    library(caTools)
    split <-sample.split(df1, SplitRatio = 0.5)
    split
    training <- subset(df1, split == "TRUE")
    testing <- subset(df1, split == "FALSE")
```

The error:

> Error: Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector. i Logical
> subscripts must match the size of the indexed input. x Input has size
> 333030 but subscript i has size 9. Run rlang::last_error() to see
> where the error occurred.

Comment: Don't ever put `"TRUE"` and "FALSE"` in quotes - that makes them strings, not logical values. That's not your issue here necessarily, but it is best practice.

Comment: I'd try `training = df1[split, ]` and `testing = df1[!split, ]` but maybe checkout `head(split)` to make sure it's true/false values, and `length(split)` compared to `nrow(df1)` to make sure the sizes are right.

Comment: Removing the quotes does not solve the problem in this case. split has 9 values, either TRUE or FALSE. I think that is causing the problem. I have 333,030 rows in df1, as indicated in the error message. Meanwhile, what split ratio should I be using? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are splitting on the columns. If you read the help page:

> Usage:
>
> ```
>   sample.split( Y, SplitRatio = 2/3, group = NULL )
>   Arguments:
>
>    Y: Vector of data labels. If there are only a few labels (as is
>       expected) than relative ratio of data in both subsets will be
>       the same.
> ```

You are providing the whole data frame, which it reads as a list.So if you have a dependent variable, for example `y` , it would be:

```
split <-sample.split(df1$y, SplitRatio = 0.5)
training <- df1[split,]
testing <- df1[!split,]
```

Or

```
split <-sample.split(1:nrow(df1), SplitRatio = 0.5)
training <- df1[split,]
testing <- df1[!split,]
```